# sorting a file numerically even though there are letters in it

Tags: python-3.x, file, sorting, numbers

how would I sort something like this numerically?

GDcheerios.38265484009

BirdPigeon.2051412858

peterparkermj.66848470

those are all in scores.txt

```
#reading the file lines
  with open("scores.txt") as f:
    names_scores = f.read().splitlines()

  #sorting player scores
  player_sort = []

  for line in names_scores:
    player_sort.append(line)

  player_sort.sort()
  print(player_sort)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in [**`sorted()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function to sort your list using a key function that splits on a `.` and selects the last integer element as your comparison key for every item present in the list.

```
names_scores = [
    "BirdPigeon.2051412858", "GDcheerios.38265484009", "peterparkermj.66848470",
]
print(sorted(names_scores, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)[-1])))
```

**Output:**

```
['peterparkermj.66848470', 'BirdPigeon.2051412858', 'GDcheerios.38265484009']
```